# if $x_{1}=\frac{1}{2},x_{n+1}=bx_{n}(1-x_{n})$How prove $\{x_{2k}\},\{x_{2k+1}\}$ have The opposite monotonicity

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

**Question:**

> difine the sequence $\{x_{n}\}$,such $$x_{1}=\dfrac{1}{2},x_{n+1}=bx_{n}(1-x_{n}),n\in N^{+},b>0$$

show that: when $3<b\le 1+\sqrt{5}$;

> then subsequence $\{x_{2k}\},\{x_{2k+1}\}$ have The opposite monotonicity,and converge to different limit.

My idea: since
$$x_{n+1}-x_{n}=bx_{n}-bx^2_{n}-x_{n}=(1-b)x_{n}-bx^2_{n}$$

This problem is from  < Mathematical analysis problem sets handout>,In china, it is well know this book is hard,and some problem is from AMM problem,and this book can download by  this PDF:
[link](http://ishare.iask.sina.com.cn/f/13307764.html)

Thank you for you help

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=bx(1-x)$ and define $g(x)=f\circ f(x)$.

(1) It is not difficult to check that
$$
g(x)-x=-b^3 x(x-u)(x-v)(x-w)
$$
with $u=\frac{1+b-\sqrt{(b+1)(b-3)}}{2b}$, $v=\frac{b-1}{b}$ and 
$w=\frac{1+b+\sqrt{(b+1)(b-3)}}{2b}$, and it is an easy task to note that $u<v<w$. Morover, $\frac{1}{2}\leq u\iff (b-1)^2\leq 5$, so, under the assumption $3\leq b\leq1+\sqrt{5}$, we have $\frac{1}{2}\leq u$, and for $x\in[\frac{1}{2},u]$ we have $g(x)\geq x$.

(2) On the other hand,  $g'(x)=-2b^3(2x-1)\left(  x^2- x+\frac{1}{2b}\right)$. The equation $x^2-x-\frac{1}{2b}=0$ has two zeros, one is smaller than $\frac{1}{2}$ and the other one  $t:=\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{b-2}{4b} }$ is larger than $\frac{1}{2}$. In fact,
 $t>u$, because this is equivalent to $$\sqrt{b(b-2)}>1-\sqrt{(b+1)(b-3)}$$ which is trivially true since the left hand side is larger than
$\sqrt{3(3-2)}=\sqrt{3}$ and the right hand side is smaller than $1$. This discussion shows that $g'(x)> 0$ for $x\in\left(\frac{1}{2},u\right)$. That is $g$ is increasing on the interval
$\left[\frac{1}{2},u\right]$. Combining, this with (1) and the fact that $g(u)=u$ we conclude that, for every $x\in \left[\frac{1}{2},u\right)$ we have
$$
\frac{1}{2}\leq x <g(x)<u.\tag{*}
$$

(3) From (*) and the facts that $x_1=\frac{1}{2}$, and $x_{2n+1}=g(x_{2n-1})$, we can prove by an easy induction that, for every $n\geq1$ 
$$
\frac{1}{2}\leq x_{2n-1}<x_{2n+1}<u.
$$
Thus, the sequence $\langle x_{2n+1}\rangle$ is increasing and bounded, so it must converge to a limit $\ell$ that satisfy $\frac{1}{2}\leq \ell\leq u$ and $g(\ell)=\ell$.
Using (1) again we see that we must have $\ell=u$. So, the sequence $\langle x_{2n+1}\rangle$ is increasing and
$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_{2n+1}=u$.

(4) Now, the function $f$ is continuous decreasing on $[\frac{1}{2},1]$, and
$x_{2n}=f(x_{2n-1})$, So from (3) we conclude that the sequence $\langle x_{2n}\rangle$
is decreasing and that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_{2n}=f(u)=w$.
The desired conclusion follows since $u\ne w$, (here we use the fact that $b>3$.)